# How to insert SPARQL data with POST request body in Blazegraph?

Tags: blazegraph

I'm using Blazegraph as my RDF store. I'm trying to insert data in the following format:

```
INSERT DATA {
     <http://www.test.com/1> <http://www.test.com/2> <http://www.test.com/3> .
     ...
}
```

Now, if I use the URL `update` parameter like `http://localhost:9999/bigdata/sparql?update=QUERY` it works just fine, but the problem is that when the data is too long it will exceed the allowed length of the URI.

So is there a way to execute this same query but sending it in the request body?

I tried just doing a post request to `http://localhost:9999/bigdata/sparql` with the query as request body but I get a syntax error from the server saying it doesn't expect `INSERT`, but rather a `SELECT`, `DESCRIBE` or other statements. I guess it is not understanding correctly that I'm trying to do an `INSERT` and maybe I need to send some additional headers/paramters to signal that.